# Why is mut self in Trait Implementation allowed when Trait definition only uses self?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm working on the `traits2.rs` exercise in rustlings and am confused on Rust's syntax for traits. I have the following working solution (that compiles and passes the test, I'm using Rust 1.50):

```rust
trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self;
}

impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(mut self) -> Self {
        self.push("Bar".into());
        self
    }
}
```

However, I'm confused that, while the trait definition is `fn append_bar(self) -> Self`, my implementation for it is `fn append_bar(mut self) -> Self`, which has an additional `mut` on the signature. Why is this allowed?

Comment: Since you're moving the value anyway, the mutability isn't important to the type signature. It's like you can do `let mut mutable_value = immutable_value;` to "convert" an immutable value into a mutable one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Reference for associated functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/associated-items.html?highlight=asso#associated-functions-and-methods) says:

> The identifier is the name of the function. The generics, parameter list, return type, and where clause of the associated function must be the same as the associated function declarations's.

Matching the parameter list means matching the number and types of parameters.
The [Reference for functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/functions.html) explains the structure of a parameter:

> FunctionParam :
> OuterAttribute* Pattern : Type

Where `Pattern` in this case is an [Identifier Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html):

> IdentifierPattern :
> ref? mut? IDENTIFIER (@ Pattern ) ?

This induces that `mut` is part of the pattern, not part of the type which is the reason why `mut` (unlike `&mut`) is not part of the Signature at all, so thats why you are allowed to use it.

It's important to note here that `mut self` vs `self` is not the same as `&self` vs `&mut self`. As with other parameters, the `mut` in `mut self` is just an annotation on the binding of `self`, not the type.

The caller does not need to know about it: you move the value one way or the other, so it's up to the callee if it needs to mutate it or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It makes a lot of sense but could you point me to some documentation where this behavior is documented? Thanks!

Comment: @cicolus I edited my answer with a few links to the official rust language reference, if you think my answer is still not satisfactory let me now, otherwise it would be cool to accept it as the best answer

Comment: Thanks so much for the edit! It perfectly answers my question :)

Comment: The last line was the most helpful to me: "The caller does not need to know about it: you move the value one way or the other, so it's up to the callee if it needs to mutate it or not."